# CSS - Overriding grid / parent rules for containers

Tags: html, css

I'm building a site using reset & skeleton grid. I've also set rules for the body and a general container rule -

```
body {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
}
```

I've seperated sections of the site using containers/rows/columns. How do I override these rules for specific containers? For example, I have a container for a contact form and split into four & eight columns. I need it to stretch out to accomodate both the contact details and the form but currently I'm getting this (box shadow is the edge of the body) - 
[image: Contact form]

I've tried setting width rules for the columns but nothing changes -

```
section#form {
    height: 300px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#form .four {
    width: 300px;

}

#form .eight {
    max-width: 100%
}
```

I have a similar issue with a block of images which I need to stretch out but am unable. Any asistance appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean 'stretch out to accommodate code'? Are you trying to make one of the containers responsive, or a column, or part of a column? I'm a bit confused by your question.

Comment: @PaigeMeinke Sorry, that's poorly worded and will change. What I mean is that I may want certain containers to be more flexible in terms of width and margin.

Comment: If you want flexibility, dump the hard fixed pixel widths and change for percentages.